# reference states for activities

Tags: reaction-mechanism, equilibrium

I wanted to ask clarifications about a passage in Atkin's physical chemistry book, chapter 9, in the paragraph 9.2 description of equilibrium.

For studying equilibrium of a reaction, where $\nu_i$ are the stechiometric coefficients it imposes $\sum_i \nu_i \mu_i=0$ with $\mu$ the chemical coefficients. At this point it writes the chemical coefficients as a function of the activities $\mu_i=\mu_i^\circ+RT\ln(a_i)$ and identifies the term $\sum_i \nu_i \mu_i^\circ$ with the standard reaction Gibbs energy. I do not understand this identification. I thought that the standard state for the definition of activities (even dependent on wether the substance is a solute or a solvent) was not the same reference state for computing the reaction Gibbs energy (and does not depend on the role played by the substance in the reaction). I'm surely getting something wrong...

Answer (score 2):

$\mu_i=\mu_i^o+RT ln(a_i)$ is the [definition of activity](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00115.html) ($a_i$).

Therefore, the [standard state](http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05925.html) for [standard chemical potential](http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05908.html) ($\mu_i^o$) is necessarily part of the definition of activity.

For a pure liquid or solid, the standard state is the pure substance at 1 bar.

For a liquid solvent, the standard state is also the pure liquid at 1 bar.

For a gas, the standard state is the fictitious state of an ideal gas at 1 bar.

For solutes, there are multiple conventions, for example the fictitious state of the solute having a molality of 1 mole/kilogram and exhibiting the behavior it does at infinite dilution.

$\Delta G^o = \sum_i \nu_i \mu_i^o$ by definition.

So there is no one standard state for $\Delta G^o$, because the various substances may have different standard states.

Comment: Actually Atkins says that for a solute the $\mu_i^0$ is your equation is defined as $\mu_i^0=\mu_i^*+RT ln(K_B/p^*_B)$, where $\mu_i^*$ is the chemical potential of the pure solute at the same temperature, $p^*_B$ the vapour pressure of the pure solute ad that pressure, and $K_B$ the constant given bu Henry's rule. I think this is the chemical potential of the pure substance when the vapour pressure is $K_B$ (not sure) but anyway I do not see here a link with the standard conditions (1 bar) that are used to define the standard Gibs free energy of reaction...

Comment: I wanted to say that $p_B$ is the vapour pressure at that temperature (I do noto think the external pressure plays a role).. I also used i and B ad the same symbol I'm sorry bit I'm noto able to edit the message...

Comment: @tirrel The way you and/or Atkins have $\mu_i^o =$ (function of temperature) doesn't make sense. Should $\mu_i^o$ just be $\mu_i$? The closest equation that I know of to what you have written is $\mu_i = \mu_i^* +RTln(x_i)$ for an ideal solution and $P_i = K_ix_i$ for Henry's law and $P_i = x_iP_i^*$ for Raoult's law.

Comment: DavePhD: this is what I understand from Atkins, which is a well respected book, so maybe I do not understand it. The section is 7.2, if you want to have a look.
By the way in your equation $μ_i=μ^∗_i+RTln(x_i)$, which also appears in Atkin's book how do you interpret the symbols? I though that $μ^∗_i$ was the chemical potential of the pure substance at the temperature given (so it is temperature dependent). And by the way if $x_i=1$ we get $μ_i=μ^∗_i$, which suggests to me that the reference state must indeed be temperature dependent.

Comment: @tirrel I agree Atkins is a great book, but I don't have it at home, only Levine.  The superscript in $\mu_i^o$ means "standard state" and the superscript in $\mu_i^*$ means "pure state".  The equation $\mu_i=\mu_i^*+RTln(x_i)$ doesn't say anything about the standard state, and isn't generally true, it is an ideal-law type of equation.  Make sure you check if the equations are true generally, or just in some ideal condition, and whether Atkins says $\mu_i^o$ or $\mu_i$

Comment: As far as I understand, Atkins says that: $μ_i =μ^∗_i +RTln(p_i/p^*_i)$ is the equation valid for every real solution where $p_i$ is the partial pressure at a certain composition and temperature $T$ and $p^*_i$ is the vapor pressure of the pure substance. For solvents activity is defined as $p_i/p^*_i$ and therefore we get $μ_i =μ^∗_i +RTln(a_i)$. This equation is generally true and $a_i$ tends to $x_i$ for $x_i$ that tends to one (Raoult's law). This for solvents. For solutes we have Henry's low and I already wrote the equations (of general validity) that I've understood...

Comment: Maybe we can just concentrate on solvents for the time being and then we pass to solutes, which seem to be more complicated... Do you agree with the definition I posted or do you have an other one?

Comment: For solvent, the standard state is the pure solvent at 1bar (according to IUPAC), and $\mu=\mu^*+RTln(a)$, where activity ($a$) could be written as $\gamma x$, $\gamma$ being the activity coefficient and $x$ being mole fraction (according to Levine).

Comment: According to your definition DavePHD $\mu^*$ depends on temperature. The only condition is to be at $1 bar$, which actually I think that at normal conditions is not very important, since the vapour pressure of a pure substance should depend very little on external pressure

Comment: Anyway, what about solutes, which are more complicated? And then, if the standard conditions are different in the two cases, as I'm getting to believe (what does Levine says?), how do I know from a table that a certain substance is a solvent or a solute (according to the experimental conditions, it can be the former or the latter...)?

Comment: Now I'm looking at parts of Atkin too through google books.  For solvent, Atkins equation 5E.1 is exactly the same as what I posted from Levine.  The equation you posted in your very first comment with $K_B/p^*$ is equation 5E.7, but Atkins makes clear that it is for ideally dilute solution.  Then Atkins introduces real solutes and $\mu_i=\mu_i^0+RT ln(a_i)$ is equation 5E.9, and explains that Henry's Law behavior is only approached in the limit of infinite dilution and "activity" captures the deviation from ideal behavior. (continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) Then Atkins introduces the mole fraction convention and says the standard state would be that same as that discuss in an earlier. Then Atkins discusses the molality convention and says the standard state would be different from the previous one.  Levine discuss these two convention, plus two other convention (concentration scale and treating the solute exactly the same as solvent).

Comment: Thanks DavePHD! Just a last comment: the same substance therefore can have multiple standard Gibbs chemical potentials reference states, depending if it is acting as a solvent or a solute. Right?

Comment: Yes, as Atkins puts it, "The selection of a standard state is entirely arbitrary, so we are free to choose one that best suits our purpose..." Section 5.11(c)

Answer (score 2):

So is the point of contention here "how does the standard state for the activities relate to the standard state for the Gibbs free energy change"?

To see how choice of standard state for an activity relates to the standard state chosen for the chemical potential, write the equation as

$$\mu_i = \mu_i^\circ + R T \ln a_i = \mu_i^\circ + R T \ln \frac{\gamma_i c_i}{c_i^\circ}$$

where the standard states are consistent.The standard state is being defined so that
when $\gamma_i c_i = c_i^\circ$, $\mu_i = \mu_i^\circ$. If we're using molarities, we can choose $c_i^\circ = 1\ M$.

Now suppose you want to define a standard state that's different from 1 in the units you're using for concentration; e. g, suppose we have a reaction that includes $\rm H^+$ and we want to define the biological standard state ($^\oplus$) as $c_{\rm H^+}^\oplus = 10^{-7}\ M = 10^{-7} c_{\rm H^+}^\circ$, while using molarities as our concentration unit.

We can compute a new chemical potential:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\mu_{\rm H^+} &=& \mu_{\rm H^+}^\circ + R T \ln \dfrac{\gamma_i c_{\rm H^+}}{c_{\rm H^+}^\oplus}\\
&=& \mu_{\rm H^+}^\circ + R T \ln \dfrac{\gamma_i c_{\rm H^+}}{10^{-7} c_{\rm H^+}^\circ}\\
&=& (\mu_{\rm H^+}^\circ + 7 R T\ln 10) + R T \ln \dfrac{\gamma_i c_{\rm H^+}}{c_{\rm H^+}^\circ}\\
&=& \mu_{\rm H^+}^\oplus + R T \ln \dfrac{\gamma_i c_{\rm H^+}}{c_{\rm H^+}^\circ}\\
&=& \mu_{\rm H^+}^\oplus + R T \ln a_{\rm H^+}
\end{array}$$

Now at unit activity $\gamma_i c_i = c_i^\circ$ and $\mu_i = \mu_i^\oplus$. Your chemical potential (and your Gibbs free energy changes) are now defined in terms of this new standard state. *And note that the chemical potential at this new standard state ($\mu_{\rm H^+}^\oplus$) is indeed temperature dependent*. To convert between the two standard state Gibbs free energies in this particular case,

$$\Delta G^\oplus = \Delta G^\circ + 7 \nu R T \ln 10$$

where $\nu$ is the stoichiometric coefficient of $\rm H^+$ in the reaction.

*TL;DR: The standard state you choose for the concentration at unit activity becomes the standard state for the standard state Gibbs free energy change.*