# What is meant by pure solids or pure liquids?

Tags: equilibrium

In by book, under the topic Heterogeneous Equilibrium it is given

> For pure solid and pure liquid, active mass is taken to be unity, i.e., 1 as they remain constant throughout the reaction.

Could you please explain what are the pure solids and liquids being mentioned here?

I read some related answers to similar question but none addresses which compounds are pure which are not. Or, if I haven't noticed properly, kindly give me the link to clarify my doubt.

Comment: Pure substances here refer to substances other than solutions in the liquid/gas phase, I think. For instance, Bromine in its pure state is a liquid but liquid HCl is more often than not an aqueous solution.

Comment: Pure refers to the elemental state. But, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/reference-states-for-activities pretty much answers it.

Comment: Can you please give the name of that book?